# How to delete a record depending on the following record

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with the following columns: (Car, User, Location, Time, Type)

The type can be:

- **'OUT'** if the user's request to rent the car is accepted
- **'IN'** when the user stops using the car and registers it back into the system
- **'DENIED'** when the access to rent the car is denied

So the order of the records regarding to the type should be OUT-IN (time ascending)

There are inconsistent data where there might be several rows with the same car,user,location and type values following each other like below

| Car | User | Location | Time | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ben | Chicago | 2022-02-12 03:12:45 | OUT //should be deleted |
| 1 | Ben | Chicago | 2022-02-12 04:12:45 | OUT //should be deleted |
| 2 | Sam | New York | 2022-02-12 04:42:45 | OUT |
| 1 | Ben | Chicago | 2022-02-12 04:50:00 | OUT //should be kept |
| 1 | Sam | New York | 2022-02-12 07:32:12 | IN |
| 1 | Ben | Chicago | 2022-02-12 08:18:45 | IN //should be deleted |
| 3 | Mia | San Franc | 2022-02-12 09:12:43 | OUT |
| 1 | Ben | Chicago | 2022-02-12 09:27:23 | IN //should be kept |

So only the last OUT and IN records should be kept and the other duplicates should be removed.

To make it easier for help

```
CREATE TABLE rent_logs (
    car      varchar(30),
    user     varchar(30),
    location varchar(30),
    time     datetime
    type     varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO rent_logs ( car, username, location, time, type ) VALUES
( 1, 'Ben', 'Chicago','2022-02-12 03:12:45',  'OUT' ), 
( 1, 'Ben', 'Chicago',' 2022-02-12 04:12:45  ',  'OUT' ), 
( 2, 'Sam', 'New york','2022-02-12 04:42:45',  'OUT' ), 
( 1, 'Ben', 'Chicago','2022-02-12 04:50:00',  'OUT' ), 
( 2, 'Sam', 'New york','2022-02-12 07:32:12 ',  'IN' ), 
( 1, 'Ben', 'Chicago','22022-02-12 08:18:45',  'IN' ), 
( 3, 'Mia', 'Chicago','2022-02-12 09:12:43',  'OUT' ), 
( 1, 'Ben', 'Chicago','2022-02-12 09:27:23',  'IN' )
```

Comment: how does this inconsistency come about in the first place?

Comment: The system malfunctioning i believe. I have only been provided the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pair of window functions on the `Type` field:

- [`LAG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag), to retrieve the previous value
- [`LEAD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead), to retrieve the next value

These window functions will apply according to specific partitions involving the following fields in this order: `User`, `Car`, `Location`.

Once you get these values, you can retrieve the rows when one of the following conditions on the field `Type` is met:

- `Type = OUT` and `TypeNext = IN` (last `OUT`)
- `Type = IN` and `TypePrev = IN` and not `TypeNext = IN` (last `IN`)
- `Type = DENIED`

If you have more complex conditions on near rows, you can handle them through these three computed values.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Car,
           User,
           Location,
           Time,
           LAG(Type) OVER(
               PARTITION BY User, Car, Location 
               ORDER BY Time)                    AS TypePrev,
           Type,
           LEAD(Type) OVER(
               PARTITION BY User, Car, Location 
               ORDER BY Time)                    AS TypeNext
    FROM rent_logs 
)
SELECT Car,
       User,
       Location,
       Time,
       Type
FROM cte
WHERE (Type = 'OUT' AND TypeNext = 'IN') 
   OR (Type = 'IN'  AND TypePrev = 'IN' AND (TypeNext = 'OUT' OR TypeNext IS NULL))
   OR (TypePrev IS NULL AND TypeNext IS NULL)
   OR (Type = 'DENIED')
ORDER BY User, 
         Time
```

Check the SQL Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wesLUAmC1d7UAsEHMHq94s/1).

If you want to play a bit to understand how it works and the intermediate result in the fiddle link, I'd suggest to remove comments from the commented lines and to comment the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This doesn't really tackle the issue I'm having. This affects the DENIED rows as well and it removes all duplicates of that row keeping the last only. But this wasn't the goal. Suppose there's another instance of Ben renting the same car again in the same location a month later .This would delete those records as well.

I want something that deletes the similar records UNTIL the type changes from OUT to IN or from IN to OUT

Comment: I was misled by the provided output, maybe now it will behave as you intended. Does it solve your problem? @SerdaShehu

Comment: I changed the last part to

**FROM cte
WHERE NOT (Type = 'OUT' AND TypeNext = 'OUT') AND NOT (Type = 'IN' AND TypeNext = 'IN') A
ORDER BY time asc**

and now it seems to fulfill my requirements completely. Thank you very much i really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Glad you'll be able to recover from system malfunctioning!